# REST call to spring boot RestController results 404 in tomcat but works in embedded tomcat

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot. I have knowledge on Spring mvc. I have developed small application with one @RestController as mentioned in Update below. This is working fine when I execute using `mvn spring-boot:run` (ie. embedded tomcat)

1. The same REST call results in `404 not found` when I deploy as packaged war to tomcat. Target url
   http://localhost:8086/myapp/demo gives 404.
2. I have the `log4j2.xml` created and when I execute with embedded tomcat it creates the expected log file, but with the external tomcat deployment it does not create the log file too and I do not find any logs in any of the tomcat logs under `<tomcat-dir>/logs`

What am I missing here ?

UPDATE:

The spring boot entry point class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class App extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(
            SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(App.class);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/demo")
    public String demo() {
        return "Helloo.. !!";
    }
}
```

Spring boot version => v1.3.2.RELEASE

The logs when I deploy to tcServer

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\Users\a\vfabric-tc-server\vm1\webapps\myapp.war
Sep 12, 2016 5:07:23 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\a\vfabric-tc-server\vm1\webapps\myapp\WEB-INF\lib\tomcat-embed-el-8.0.30.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Sep 12, 2016 5:07:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Sep 12, 2016 5:07:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration$JerseyWebApplicationInitializer@47b35d]
Sep 12, 2016 5:07:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive C:\Users\a\vfabric-tc-server\vm1\webapps\myapp.war has finished in 1,913 ms
```

UPDATE1:
I removed Angular, kept only spring boot @restcontroller. Problem still exists.

Comment: How did you create the war file I.e. via maven? Does it have web.xml file?

Comment: Yes I am creating via maven and it does not have web.xml

Comment: @notionquest please check update in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the problem with the target external Tomcat server that was pointing to `JDK6`, but my application was build using `jdk7`.
Problem resolved once I point the external Tomcat to `jdk7`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the scope of the Tomcat embedded server to "provided" in your POM file or for deployment into a non-embedded Tomcat container, better off to exclude the JAR (so commenting it out is also a good option).

I had faced a similar issue with the old v1.3.x of Spring BOOT. I have not observed this in the new version i.e., v1.4.0.

I'm assuming that you are using Spring BOOT parent POM and "spring-boot-starter" lib in your project POM.

Comment: @Sridhar Okay. May not be related but just out of curiosity, why do you have to override the configure method ? I havent done it for any of my projects to get it started. Official guides do not mention it too https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/